# Chain complex of free modules

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a chain complex of free R modules. Let $Z_n=\ker(d_n)$ and $B_n=\operatorname{Im}(d_{n+1})$ where $d_n :\to X_n \to X_{n-1}$. Then how can I conclude that the short exact sequence $0 \to Z_n \to X_n \to B_{n-1} \to 0$ is split? How can we write $X_n=Z_n \oplus B_{n-1}$?

Please help me

Comment: For this to be true, you need some hypothesis, like R a PID. In that case, the group of boundaries, being a submodule of a free module, is itself free and, therefore, projective. And if it is projective...

Comment: yes I have the assumption that R is a PID. Then how to proceed?

Comment: If you have that assumption, then make it explicit in the body of the question. You can proceed as I explained in my comment.

Comment: Yes I got the proof. Thank you

Comment: Is it true if I assume X is a flat chain complex over a PID R?

Comment: Please **edit** the question so that it contains all the needed hypotheses